# Why isn't my database updating in a class when I use the command to update it in a another class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I think my SQL queries is working but the data of my table is not updating. Why is that?

I have a table in my database named **MasterStudents** with column names **StudentID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, FirstName VARCHAR, LastName VARCHAR, ContactNumber VARCHAR, EmailAddress VARCHAR**

I have two classes, **StudentsMasterList.java** - makes a Table layout that display data in a database using a Table Row & **StudentsFormUpdate.java** that retrieves the data of the selected Table Row and displays it in EditText/s.

I have a button in the StudentsFormUpdate that calls the function UpdateButton() onClick.

This is the StudentsFormUpdate.java class (Updated):

```js
public class StudentsFormUpdate extends Activity
{
    String FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, ContactNumber, StudentID;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TextView StudentIDViewUpdate2;
    EditText FirstNameUpdate2, LastNameUpdate2, ContactNumberUpdate2, EmailUpdate2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.students_updateform);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("ClassManager", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

        String reciever = getIntent().getStringExtra("sender");

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MasterStudents WHERE StudentID = '" + reciever + "'", null);

        TextView StudentIDViewUpdate2  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.StudentIDViewPermanentUpdate);
        EditText FirstNameUpdate2      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstNameTextUpdate);
        EditText LastNameUpdate2       = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastNameTextUpdate);
        EditText ContactNumberUpdate2  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ContactNumberTextUpdate);
        EditText EmailUpdate2          = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailAddressTextUpdate);


        c.moveToFirst();
        StudentIDViewUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StudentID")));
        FirstNameUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName")));
        LastNameUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
        ContactNumberUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")));
        EmailUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EmailAddress")));


    }

    public void UpdateButton(View view)
    {

        StudentID = StudentIDViewUpdate2.getText().toString();
        FirstName = FirstNameUpdate2.getText().toString();
        LastName = LastNameUpdate2.getText().toString();
        ContactNumber = ContactNumberUpdate2.getText().toString();
        EmailAddress = EmailUpdate2.getText().toString();

        db.execSQL("UPDATE MasterStudents SET FirstName = '" + FirstName + "', LastName = '" + LastName + "', ContactNumber = '" + ContactNumber + "', " +
                   "EmailAddress = '" + EmailAddress + "' WHERE StudentID = " + StudentID + ";");

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Why isn't my code working? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what's wrong here? Does it crash?

Comment: It doesn't crash, there are no errors. When I pressed the button calling the function UpdateButton() the data that I updated doesn't change when I go back to StudentsMasterList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `StudentsFormUpdate` class with the following code:

```
public class StudentsFormUpdate extends Activity
{
String FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, ContactNumber, StudentID;
SQLiteDatabase db;
TextView StudentIDViewUpdate2;
EditText FirstNameUpdate2, LastNameUpdate2, ContactNumberUpdate2, EmailUpdate2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.students_updateform);
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("ClassManager", MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

    String reciever = getIntent().getStringExtra("sender");

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MasterStudents WHERE StudentID = '" + reciever + "'", null);

    StudentIDViewUpdate2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.StudentIDViewPermanentUpdate);
    FirstNameUpdate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstNameTextUpdate);
    LastNameUpdate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastNameTextUpdate);
    ContactNumberUpdate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ContactNumberTextUpdate);
    EmailUpdate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailAddressTextUpdate);


    c.moveToFirst();
    StudentIDViewUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StudentID")));
    FirstNameUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName")));
    LastNameUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
    ContactNumberUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")));
    EmailUpdate2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EmailAddress")));


}

public void UpdateButton(View view)
{

    StudentID = StudentIDViewUpdate2.getText().toString();
    FirstName = FirstNameUpdate2.getText().toString();
    LastName = LastNameUpdate2.getText().toString();
    ContactNumber = ContactNumberUpdate2.getText().toString();
    EmailAddress = EmailUpdate2.getText().toString();

    db.execSQL("UPDATE MasterStudents SET FirstName = '" + FirstName + "', LastName = '" + LastName + "', ContactNumber = '" + ContactNumber + "', " +
               "EmailAddress = '" + EmailAddress + "' WHERE StudentID = " + StudentID + ";");

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: The edittexts when inserted to UpdateButton is not detected by the function.

Comment: Declare them before `onCreate` like `TextView StudentIDViewUpdate2; EditText FirstNameUpdate2, LastNameUpdate2, ContactNumberUpdate2, EmailUpdate2;`

Comment: I got this error: 02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): Process: test.com.classmanagertest, PID: 14608
02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: At which line? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, if you can update your code with the changes I suggested above, it would be better to trace the error.

Comment: Where do i get the stack trace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70156/discussion-between-prerak-sola-and-kreyah).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! But I have one last question. When I press the Update button and go back to the StudentsMasterList the old values are still there. Is there a function that refreshes my database when I press the Update Button?

Comment: Don't press the back button. Instead call `StudentsMasterList` in the `UpdateButton()` via  `intent`. This should refresh your `StudentsMasterList` activity.

Comment: But can I set the intent in the back button?

Comment: I don't have any idea about that. You can google it. Maybe you will find something.

Answer (score 0):

StudentID is an Integer, so the encapsulating `""` is not needed in your update query.

Change your update query from

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE MasterStudents SET FirstName = '" + FirstName + "', LastName = '" + LastName + "', ContactNumber = '" + ContactNumber + "', " +
                   "EmailAddress = '" + EmailAddress + "' WHERE StudentID = '" + StudentID + "'");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE MasterStudents SET FirstName = '" + FirstName + "', LastName = '" + LastName + "', ContactNumber = '" + ContactNumber + "', " +
                   "EmailAddress = '" + EmailAddress + "' WHERE StudentID = " + StudentID +";");
```

Note: you should set `StudentID` as a `primary key` in your database. Don't set it just `unique`.

Also, add this code from `onCreate` to `UpdateButton` after making the `EditText` global variables.

```
private TextView StudentIDViewUpdate2;
private EditText FirstNameUpdate2;
private EditText LastNameUpdate2;
private EditText ContactNumberUpdate2;
private EditText EmailUpdate2;
```

In your `onCreate`

```
StudentIDViewUpdate2  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.StudentIDViewPermanentUpdate);
FirstNameUpdate2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FirstNameTextUpdate);
LastNameUpdate2       = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastNameTextUpdate);
ContactNumberUpdate2  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ContactNumberTextUpdate);
EmailUpdate2          = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailAddressTextUpdate);
```

From `onCreate` to `UpdateButton`

```
StudentID = StudentIDViewUpdate2.getText().toString(); 
FirstName = FirstNameUpdate2.getText().toString(); 
LastName = LastNameUpdate2.getText().toString(); 
ContactNumber = ContactNumberUpdate2.getText().toString(); 
EmailAddress = EmailUpdate2.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I got this error: 02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): Process: test.com.classmanagertest, PID: 14608
02-04 00:20:14.278: E/AndroidRuntime(14608): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity